# Disable transactions in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

How do I disable transactions in Rails' ActiveRecord? I have a specific situation where I want them to go away I can't seem to find anything useful out there. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poor man's "no transactions"

```
# Force the loading of AR stuff
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT 1')

# Remove transactions
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter.class_eval do
  def begin_db_transaction
  end

  def commit_db_transaction
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Daniel's answer but I found I had to also disable savepoints to function. Tested on Rails 3.2.22.2.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.class_eval do
  def begin_db_transaction
  end

  def commit_db_transaction
  end

  def create_savepoint
  end

  def rollback_to_savepoint
  end

  def release_savepoint
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

transaction is a class method on ActiveRecord::Base so you can do it like this:

```
Model.transaction do
  ...
end
```

or if you prefer to do it without a specific model:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ...
end
```

It may also depend on which database you are using, I know for sure that works on mysql but not sure about others.

Comment: You misread the question. I want to disable transactions, not use them. Your examples explicitly use transactions.

ActiveRecord uses transactions at various points, and those are the ones I want to remove.

Comment: Marked this one down for being irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mcostanza. This works for me, even if it doesn't for the OP.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344247/rails-transactions: "It's unnecessary to disable autocommit mode to use transactions in MySQL. Simply begin a transaction explicitly."

Comment: Surely "Disabling transactions" just means "do the following in a single transaction"? In which case this is the correct answer..